# Windows XP SP3 - Upgrade - No longer part of workgroup

Tags: windows-xp, sp3

When I woke up this morning I decided to have a really lousy day.  For a long time I have been telling auto updater to remind me later about installing SP3.  But not this morning...

It looked good, until I tried to access my NAS.  Can't connect, can't see it, nothing.  The other computers can see it, so it is my PC.  Oh, and they can no longer see me.  It turns out the only thing I can see is the printer.

So if you know what wonderful thing Microsoft decided to change during the upgrade (oxymoron in my opinion), I would be grateful.  Short of turning on all of the services I have tried so many things, and rebooted so often, that I am just sick of it.

Comment: @`...I decided to have a really lousy day. For a long time I have been telling auto updater to remind me later about installing SP3. But not this morning...` +1

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. faced a similar thing myself, random sporadic network irritation, try this at the command prompt, then reboot:

```
netsh int ip reset > c:\resetlog.txt
```

It reinstalls your TCP/IP stack, which fixed the errors for me.

Comment: I tried that and big M's "FixIt" program that is supposed to do the same thing, no joy.

Comment: Did you ever get it working? (if so, what did you do?)